# How to align a progress bar inside a status bar?

Tags: c#, winforms, statusbar, alignment

How can I align the highlighted progress bar to right of the status bar?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the `Spring`-Property of one of the status bar items on the left side of the `ProgressBar`to `true`, e.g. the `ToolStripStatusLabel` holding the text `Loading...`.